# Fix degraded SSD performance on Mac without full erase

Tags: macos, mac, performance, ssd, speed

I bought one of Intel's SSD a few months back. When I bought it I could easily reach the advertised speed but after a few months it has degraded very badly. Most any action that requires writing to the SSD drive has a 3-5 second pause before it happens. I've read [here](http://macperformanceguide.com/Storage-SSD-Reconditioning.html) how you can "recondition" the drive by reformatting and writing zero's through the data. I've tried that to varying levels of success before, but now I'm wondering if there is a way to fix the degraded speed issue without reformatting. It sounds like we need a tool like `wiper.exe` for mac/linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the best way to reclaim the initial speed of the device was by using GParted and doing a secure erase of the drive. I'm still waiting for Apple to release trim for a more permanent solution.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=841182

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is TRIM support, and it seems as if OSX doesn't have that yet.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact, I'm wondering if there is anything I can do in the mean time?